# PHP: Combine and sort two multidimensional arrays with same value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays in PHP, the first one being

```
[0] => [
'id' => 123,
'name' => 'John'
],

[1] => [
'id' => 456,
'name' => 'Anna'
],

[2] => [
'id' => 789,
'name' => 'Mario'
]
```

And the second one is like this:

```
[0] => [
'id' => 123,
'position' => 3
],

[1] => [
'id' => 456,
'position' => 1
],

[2] => [
'id' => 789,
'position' => 2
]
```

I'm trying to get a union of the two arrays without replacing any value. I just want to add 'position' to the first array and also sort by this new value in the meantime, like this:

```
[0] => [
'id' => 456,
'name' => 'Anna',
'position' => 1
],

[1] => [
'id' => 789,
'name' => 'Mario',
'position' => 2
],

[2] => [
'id' => 123,
'name' => 'John',
'position' => 3
]
```

How can achieve this result in the most efficient way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an array mapping ids to positions, and then loop through the a first of names (or a copy), and add the positions.

```
<?php
$names =
[
    [
        'id' => 123,
        'name' => 'John'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 456,
        'name' => 'Anna'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 789,
        'name' => 'Mario'
    ]
];

$positions =
[
    [
        'id' => 123,
        'position' => 3
    ],
    [
        'id' => 456,
        'position' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 789,
        'position' => 2
    ]
];
$id_positions = array_column($positions, 'position', 'id');
$result = $names;
foreach($result as &$item) {
    $item['position'] = $id_positions[$item['id']] ?? null;
}
unset($item);

uasort($result, function($a, $b) { return $a['position'] <=> $b['position']; });
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 456,
    'name' => 'Anna',
    'position' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 789,
    'name' => 'Mario',
    'position' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 123,
    'name' => 'John',
    'position' => 3,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked perfectly fine. I still need to sort by position, is there any way to do this during the array creation or I need to sort it after the creation?

Comment: Oh forgive me, I didn't read the sort, have added a post sort.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems like this can be solved also with just a few lines of code using this extern PHP class [tableArray](https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray).

```
$result = tableArray::create($names)
  ->leftJoinOn($positions,'t2','id','id')
  ->select('id,name,t2.position AS position')
  ->orderBy('position ASC')
  ->fetchAll()
;
```